# Why is my java SQL code hanging without throwing an exception?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm writing a component of a java application that pulls data out of a sql database by executing a proc with various different parameters.  This is intended to sometimes work on large datasets where it will need to be able to run for hours to get all the data it needs.

I have been continuously encountering an issue where my program seems to hang indefinitely.  I've seen this happen both on preparedStatement.execute() and resultSet.next().  It doesn't throw any exception, it just hangs at that line.

I have been mainly running into this issue when attempting to run overnight tests, making it costly and hard to replicate.  I saw a similar issue where my connection was dropping mid execution and throwing an exception, but I was able to modify my code to reconnect when that happens.

This is my code running the proc and parsing the results, the proc returns 4 resultsets so this is made to handle that.  The hanging always seems to occur in here somewhere.

```
final String sql = "EXEC " + "procname" + " ?";
final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, phrase);
preparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(30);
boolean resultsRemaining = preparedStatement.execute();
if (resultsRemaining) {
    while (resultsRemaining) {
        final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
        final boolean resultsEmpty = !resultSet.next();
        for (LearnableAttribute la : LearnableAttribute.values()) {
            final String dbName = la.getDbName().toUpperCase();
            final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            for (int i = 0; i < metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                final String colName = metaData.getColumnName(i + 1);
                if (colName.toUpperCase().equals(dbName)) mad.map.put(la, resultsEmpty ? null : resultSet.getString(la.getDbName()));
            }
        }
        resultsRemaining = preparedStatement.getMoreResults();
        resultSet.close();
    }
    if (LearnableAttribute.values().length != mad.map.size()) throw new RuntimeException();
    mad.map.put(LearnableAttribute.CLASS_ATTRIBUTE, classValue);
} else throw new RuntimeException();
preparedStatement.close();
```

Comment: Add log statements.

Comment: This is only tangentially related, but JDBC has a more specific interface for stored procedures named `CallableStatement` created via `connection.prepareCall`

Comment: @chrylis The full code has more logging in it, I removed it from what I posted to save space.  Those log statements are what told me that the code is getting to preparedStatement.execute() and resultSet.next() before hanging.  Is there something specific I should be logging to help diagnose this issue?

Comment: Yes, you should be turning on logging in your JDBC driver, if it supports that, and / or in the database itself.  I'm supposing that what you'll find is that your computation is stalling or taking a very long time *in the database*, and that's what you want to look at.  You may also be able to capture some of the specific queries, which you can then (separately) subject to query analysis to try to determine why they take so long, if indeed they do.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but the boolean return value of `execute()` and `getMoreResults()` does not mean what you think it means. True means that the next result is a result set, and false means the next result is an update count. Only when it is a false **and** `getUpdateCount()` returns -1 are there no more results. However, we'll need a [mcve] to be able to tell what is wrong.